# File upload with Dropzone.js using Ajax call but without using the Form tag (only div, no Form tag)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

I am trying to upload multiple files in Laravel 8 using Dropzone.js. I am trying to do this without using the Form tag. I have a div element which I have initialized with Dropzone.js. Whenever, I click on the submit button, files are not uploaded. The images are cleared out from the dropzone upload box. But, when I go and check the storage folder, there is no any file uploaded. And, also i get an error in the console which says "POST .......url....... 419 (unknown status)". How do I fix this? Please help. I am trying to upload without using Form tag, because I already have a form for other input fields to deal with. I am also not able to figure out if there is any way to submit my form with several input fields and then just below that, upload the necessary files using dropzone and post everything all at once with a submit button. Please Help. I could not find this solution anywhere.

```
    <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Documents Upload</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="dropzone" id="multipleFileUpload"></div>
            <hr>
            <a id="submit" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%">Upload</a>
        </div>
```

```
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#multipleFileUpload", 
        {
            url: '{{route("multiple.file.store")}}', 
            acceptedFiles: ".jpg,.png,.jpeg,application/pdf",
            maxFiles: 10,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            init: function () {
                var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit");
                myDropzone = this;
                submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    myDropzone.processQueue(); 
                });

                this.on('complete', function(){
                    if (this.getQueuedFiles().length == 0 && this.getUploadingFiles().length == 0) {
                        var _this = this;
                        _this.removeAllFiles();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

```
 public function storeMultipleFile(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
            $image = $request->file('file');
            $imageName = time().'.'.$image->extension();
            $image -> move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
            return response()->json(['success' => $imageName]);
        }
    }
```

```
Route::any('/storeMultipleFile', [UploadsController::class, 'storeMultipleFile'])->name('multiple.file.store');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass csrf token to post request so you need to add headers like below

```
 Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#multipleFileUpload", 
        {
            url: '{{route("multiple.file.store")}}', 
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            acceptedFiles: ".jpg,.png,.jpeg,application/pdf",
            maxFiles: 10,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            init: function () {
                var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit");
                myDropzone = this;
                submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    myDropzone.processQueue(); 
                });

                this.on('complete', function(){
                    if (this.getQueuedFiles().length == 0 && this.getUploadingFiles().length == 0) {
                        var _this = this;
                        _this.removeAllFiles();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

dont forget to add meta tag in headers

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Updated

disable autodiscovery before dropzone initialization

```
 Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
```

add input inside dropzone div

```
<div class="dropzone" id="multipleFileUpload">
 <input name="file" type="file" multiple/>
 </div>
```

Comment: Even after passing the CSRF Token as mentioned above, the problem is the same. Thankfully, the 419 error has gone. But, whenever I try to echo anything in the controller function, nothing is echoed. I doubt, the execution is not moving to the controller function. How do I deal with that?

Comment: dd($request->all()) what you get.

Comment: Also, assume that I selected 5 files for upload. So, whenever I click on the upload button, only 1 image gets uploaded, and 2 image thumbnail gets removed, then 3 remaining, I click the upload button again, another image is uploaded, and 2 thumbnails get removed. And finally, last thumbnail is left out. So, single file is being uploaded after clicking the upload button. Also, when I set parallelUploads attribute to something greater, still the problem persists. 

Meanwhile, I solved the upload using storeAs() function instead of move() function. But still, the dd() function not working.

Comment: <input name="file" type="file" multiple/> you should use multiple attribute in input

Comment: Again, the same problem. Also, the new input tag is displaying to 'Choose file' inside the dropzone area.

Comment: for input tag you can style as display:none and what you get if you dd($request->all()); in conttoller

Comment: The input tag would be of no use because I am trying to upload without using the form tag. That didn't help. I get nothing if I dd($request->all()). This is so weird. Even few times in my past, I have experienced not getting anything on dd() for many of the requests sent through ajax calls.

Comment: first check in network tab whether request hittinh that url and again why you are aovidng form tag. any specific reason ?

Comment: once you try by removing  autoProcessQueue: false, and ad  paramName: "file",

Comment: I am avoiding form tag because, I have a form having multiple input fields like a person's details. That page is working fine when I submit. Now, I want to add a feature to allow the user to add files/images too. So that, after filling all the existing form input fields, the user should be able to upload files using Dropzone. And post the existing form inputs along with the selected images/files by using the same and only one submit button.

Comment: once you try by removing autoProcessQueue: false, and ad paramName: "file",

Comment: without  full project dififcult to debug.just try from your end .first check  request hitting or not in network tab of browser console

Comment: The request is hitting on the network. It actually goes to the controller's function. Only the dd() or echo or print_r is not working there. After removing the autoProcessQueue, only 1 file gets uploaded whatever number of files I choose and the upload happens before I could click the upload button.

Comment: autoProcessQueue true will upload instantly.

Comment: add these property to dropzone   autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 10,
            maxFiles: 10,

Comment: Did it, no luck still. If I add, upload multiple property, I get 500 (Internal Server error).